# pan gesture causing flickering issue

Tags: xamarin, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on Xamarin with pan gesture.
below is source code i am using.
please help me with solution.

```
private double x, y;
var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
                panGesture.PanUpdated += (s, e) => {
                    // Handle the pan

                    switch (e.StatusType)
                    {
                        case GestureStatus.Started:
                          
                            break;
                        case GestureStatus.Running:
                             var newRectangle = new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(x+e.TotalX, y+e.TotalY, localVideoControl.Bounds.Width, localVideoControl.Bounds.Height);
                            localVideoControl.LayoutTo(newRectangle, easing: Easing.Linear);
                            break;
                        case GestureStatus.Completed:
                            break;
                    }

                };
                localVideoControl.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
```

EDITED Question:

```
var panFactor = 4.5;
                    var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
                    panGesture.PanUpdated += (s, e) => {
                        // Handle the pan

                        switch (e.StatusType)
                        {
                            case GestureStatus.Started:
                                localVideoControl.LayoutTo(new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(e.TotalX * panFactor + 100, e.TotalY * panFactor + 100, 100, 100), easing: Easing.Linear);

                                break;
                            case GestureStatus.Running:

                                //  localVideoControl.TranslationX = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(localVideoControl.Bounds.Width - Application.Current.MainPage.Width));
                                //  localVideoControl.TranslationY = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(localVideoControl.Bounds.Height - Application.Current.MainPage.Height));

                                //   var newRectangle = new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle((e.TotalX * panFactor) +(localVideoControl.Bounds.Width), (e.TotalY * panFactor) +(localVideoControl.Bounds.Height), localVideoControl.Bounds.Width, localVideoControl.Bounds.Height);

                                // var newRectangle = new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(e.TotalX + 100 , (e.TotalY + 100) , localVideoControl.Bounds.Width, localVideoControl.Bounds.Height);

                                // localVideoControl.LayoutTo(newRectangle, easing: Easing.Linear);
                                // AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(localVideoControl, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(e.TotalX- 50, e.TotalY-50, 100, 100));

                                localVideoControl.LayoutTo(new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(e.TotalX * panFactor + 100, e.TotalY * panFactor + 100, 100, 100), easing: Easing.Linear);

                                if (localVideoControl.TranslationX <= 0 ||  e.TotalX < 100 )
                                {
                                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(localVideoControl, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                                }
                                if (localVideoControl.TranslationY <= 0 || e.TotalY < 100)
                                {
                                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(localVideoControl, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                                }


                                break;
                            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                                if (localVideoControl.TranslationX > (Application.Current.MainPage.Width - 100) )
                                {
                                    localVideoControl.TranslationX = e.TotalX;
                                }
                                if (localVideoControl.TranslationY > (Application.Current.MainPage.Height - 100))
                                {
                                    localVideoControl.TranslationY = e.TotalY;
                                }

                                if (localVideoControl.TranslationX <= 0 || e.TotalX < 100)
                                {
                                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(localVideoControl, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                                }
                                if (localVideoControl.TranslationY <= 0 || e.TotalY < 100)
                                {
                                    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(localVideoControl, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
                                }

                                break;
                        }

                    };
                    localVideoControl.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
```

Comment: The structure of the code seems okay. Could you provide a simple example which could reproduce for me?  And what is the flickering issue? Could you provide the screenshot? Also you could download the source file of PanGesture for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithgestures-pangesture/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes i did that. but its not working. i had edited my question. it helps with flickering issue but now problem is it goes beyond screen width and height if i try to drag near to screen ends.

Comment: Try the binable property to set the drag mode and direction with the X,Y location. https://github.com/WendyZang/DragViewSample